# Twitter4j ¿Como listar tendencias?

Tags: java, twitter

Buen día, me estoy iniciando en el uso de la API de Twitter desde Java con la libreria Twitter4j. La mayoría de información está en inglés, y aunque ya pude listar los twets que aparecen en mi home, no he podido listar las tendencias. El código a continuación lo copié de está página pero en ingles, y me salta un error. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public class TwitterInfo_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {

        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("SGDFGDGDFGDG")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("DGDFGDFGDGDFG")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("FGHFGHGFHGFHGGF")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("DGHDFHFGHHFGFHBGFB");

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(configurationBuilder.build());
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

        ResponseList<Location> locations;
        locations = twitter.getAvailableTrends();
        System.out.println("Showing available trends");
        for (Location location : locations) {
            System.out.println(location.getName() + " (woeid:" + location.getWoeid() + ")");
        }

        Trends trends = twitter.getPlaceTrends(2295414);
        for (int i = 0; i < trends.getTrends().length; i++) {
            System.out.println(trends.getTrends()[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Me tira error en la linea `ResponseList<Location> locations;`

Answer (score 1):

lo solucioné y estoy muy feliz. Les comparto el código, porque en español hay muy poco sobre esta libreria. Buen día.

```
public class TwitterInfo_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("");

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(configurationBuilder.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

        Trends tendencias = twitter.getPlaceTrends(23424787); //La ubicación en este caso es Colombia

        for (int i = 0; i < tendencias.getTrends().length; i++) {
            System.out.println(tendencias.getTrends()[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Me alegra mucho saber que pudiste solucionarlo, también he jugado con la API de Twitter y no precisamente con una librería, por curiosidad, ¿cómo determinas la ubicación numérica de un lugar en particular?